# How to draw "particular" arrow in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce this diagram. But I can't draw the arrows? Can you help me?

Also, is there a way to uniquely define the coordinates of a point in such a way as to write for example (a) instead of (-2.5.6.0), and the same thing for the other points? thank you so much

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
%\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}


  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
     %\usepackage{mathpple}
     %\usepackage{palatino}

     \usepackage{lxfonts}


\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, xdim, ydim
{(#1) ellipse (#2 and #3)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw \boundellipse{0,0}{10}{5};
%\draw \boundellipse{4,1}{-2}{4};
\draw[very thick, fill=white] \boundellipse{-2,4}{2}{3};

\draw[very thick, fill=white] \boundellipse{4,4}{2}{3};


%%%ELEMENTI DI A

\draw [very thick,fill=black,fill opacity=1.0] (-2.5,6.0) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[color=black] (-2.5,6.0) node[below = 3] {\Large $a$};


\draw [very thick,fill=black,fill opacity=1.0] (-1.5,4.0) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[color=black] (-1.5,4.0) node[left = 3] {\Large $b$};


\draw [very thick,fill=black,fill opacity=1.0] (-2.0,2.0) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[color=black] (-2.0,2.0) node[left = 3] {\Large $c$};

\draw[color=black] (-4.0,2.0) node[left = 3] {\Huge $A$}; %%NOME INSIEME A



%%%ELEMENTI DI B

\draw [very thick,fill=black,fill opacity=1.0] (3.5,6.0) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[color=black] (3.5,6.0) node[below = 3] {\Large $1$};


\draw [very thick,fill=black,fill opacity=1.0] (2.5,4.0) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[color=black] (2.5,4.0) node[right = 3] {\Large $2$};


\draw [very thick,fill=black,fill opacity=1.0] (3.0,2.0) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[color=black] (3.0,2.0) node[right = 3] {\Large $3$};


\draw[color=black] (7.0,2.0) node[left = 3] {\Huge $B$}; %%NOME INSIEME B








\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\coordinate (a) at (-2.5,6);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get curved arrows you can do something like `\draw [->] (a) to[bend left] (b);`.

Further, as I mention in a comment you can use `\coordinate (foo) at (x,y);` to save coordinates. But might be just as easy to use a node for the dots as well, e.g. define a style like

```
  dot/.style={
    circle,fill,draw,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0
  }
```

and use

```
\node [dot,label=below:\Large$a$] (a) at (-2.5,6.0) {};
```

to make a filled black circle, with an `$a$` below it, at the specified coordinate.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, xdim, ydim
{(#1) ellipse (#2 and #3)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={
    circle,fill,draw,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0
  }]

\draw[very thick, fill=white] \boundellipse{-2,4}{2}{3};
\draw[very thick, fill=white] \boundellipse{4,4}{2}{3};


%%%ELEMENTI DI A
\node [dot,label=below:\Large$a$] (a) at (-2.5,6.0) {};
\node [dot,label=left:\Large$b$] (b) at (-1.5,4.0) {};
\node [dot,label=left:\Large$c$] (c) at (-2,2.0) {};

\node at (-4.3,2.0)  {\Huge $A$}; %%NOME INSIEME A

%%%ELEMENTI DI B
\node [dot,label=below:\Large$1$] (1) at (3.5,6.0) {};
\node [dot,label=right:\Large$2$] (2) at (2.5,4.0) {};
\node [dot,label=right:\Large$3$] (3) at (3.0,2.0) {};

\node at (6.5,2.0) {\Huge $B$}; %%NOME INSIEME B


% arrows
\begin{scope}[red,-latex]
% all paths in the scope will be red by default, with the "latex" arrow tip at the end

\draw (a) to[bend left] (1);

\draw (b) to[bend left] (1);
\draw (b) -- (2);
\draw (b) to[bend right] (3);

\draw (c) to[bend right] (3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```